# Set Environment Variable for Windows Service

Tags: .net, windows, batch-file, windows-services

I have a batch job that kicks off a windows service

```
sc serverName start serviceName
```

I'd like to set an environment variable for that service when I kick it off, similar to how you would do it for a subprocess. How can I do that with a windows service?

To clarify, I don't want to set any global environment variables, just one for that particular process. And I don't have access to the actual Service code.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @JavierGarcíaManzano sorry I did not. I ended up not using a windows service to solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapted from [this answer on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/1103091/49998):

Add a multi-string "Environment" value to the service's registry entry to the key at `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SERVICE_NAME`. Each string value should be a name=value pair, where the name is the environment variable name you want the service to have, and the value is, well, the environment variable's value.

For example, if you want your service to use a different `TEMP` and `TMP` environment variables,
[image: you would enter TEMP=VALUE as one string and TMP=VALUE as another string].

Restart the service for it to get the new environment variables.

Answer (score 6):

I'dont see wich language you use, but assuming you're using C# and your class derived from `ServiceBase` you have the method

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
```

that contains your params in the string array. So starting your service with

```
sc serverName start serviceName param1 param2
```

will do the job.

Comment: Upvoted, because for some people this will be the correct answer. In my case though I don't have access to the code for the service. Sorry I should have been explicit about that.

Comment: This also works if you use Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) in .Net 6+ and use params: --environment YourEnvVariable